# Find Earliest Date with Reference to Two Columns of Data

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel sheet with 4 columns. Column 4 is what I need.

1. Column 1- Dates when product was sold (from oldest to newest)
2. Column 2- SKU numbers of product sold
3. Column 3- Unique product SKU number
4. Column 4- should display earliest date when product was sold

Column 1 and 2 were provided information that shows what product was sold at what date. Column 3 just has Unique product SKU numbers (this was created by using Remove Duplicate values from Column 2). I would like a function that can find take Unique SKU value from Column 3, find all the matches in Column 2, then return the earliest date that product was sold. 
So next to each Column 3 cell, it should return the earliest date when the product was sold.

- I have tried address(), find (), if () statements, but no luck.

Comment: Sort your data by SKU, then by Date order and then use a `VLOOKUP()`

Comment: Welcome to SO, Robin! Here's [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and avoid down-votes.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand - using a table that looks like this (columns A, B, and C):

```
Date           SKU      Unique SKU
12/13/2014     5763     38867
5/8/2014       38867    44818
12/5/2014      42572    14723
1/5/2014       38867    31760
11/23/2014     42572    42572
2/4/2015       38867    10452
```

If you use this formula in the D column as an Array (enter with CTRL+SHIFT+Enter) , I believe it works:
`=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$7,C2),MIN(IF($B$2:$B$7=C2,$A$2:$A$7)),"")`

Answer (score 0):

```
=MIN(IF($B$2:$B$100=C2,$A$2:$A$100))
```

Array entered (Control / Shift / Enter)